# Prove that $f(E)$ is dense in $f(\Bbb R)$

Tags: continuity

Let $f$ be continuous on $\Bbb R$ and $E$ be a dense subset of $\Bbb R$.

Prove that $f(E)$ is dense in $f(\Bbb R)$

---

On the only definition of continuity

For $\forall\ \varepsilon>0$ and $\forall\ x_0\in E$,
there exists $\delta>0$ such that $\left|f(x)-f(x_0)\right|<\varepsilon$ for $\forall\ x\in E$ with $\left|x-x_0\right|<\delta$

I think It satisfies condition of dense:

There is $y$ such that $\left|f(x)-f(x_0)\right|<\varepsilon$ for each $y\in f(E)$

But... I'm not sure since it's not clear and and I doubt that only using definition of continuity can prove dense of f(E) so easily.

However, I think it can be solved with only continuous property, because this problem is in chapter of Limit and Continuous.

---

This problem is in the textbook which is published only my country (becuase my colleage's professor recently published it in 2021) and there is no solution.

Comment: $f(\mathbb{R})=f(\overline{E})\subseteq \overline{f(E)}$...

Comment: What are your thoughts? What have you tried? Where are you stuck? You need to [provide context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) for your question. Otherwise it just looks like you want somebody to do your homework for you; that's not what this site is for. If you add some appropriate context, we will be happy to help.

Comment: I'll keep your advice in mind and read provide context.

I recently found out for the first time that this site by studying non solution textbooks (as explained in the question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be a continuous function, where $E\subseteq\mathbb R$ is a dense subset.
Since $E$ is dense in $\mathbb R$ we have $\overline E=\mathbb R\implies f(\mathbb R)=f(\overline E)\subseteq\overline{f(E)}$ and this shows that $\forall  p\in f(\mathbb R)$, $p\in\overline{f(E)}$ .